# TypeError: $(...).progressbar is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I got TypeError: $(...).progressbar is not a function when Gentelella - Bootstrap Admin Template Page Load. Its affect many Jquery process. How to Fixed it.

My Error Line : (custom.js)

```
// Progressbar
if ($(".progress .progress-bar")[0]) {
    $('.progress .progress-bar').progressbar();
}
```

Footer Jquery Files

```
 <!-- jQuery -->

    <script src="{{url('vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="{{url('vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="{{url('vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <script src="{{url('vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap-wysiwyg -->
    <script src="{{url('vendors/bootstrap-wysiwyg/js/bootstrap-wysiwyg.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{url('vendors/jquery.hotkeys/jquery.hotkeys.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{url('vendors/google-code-prettify/src/prettify.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
    <script src="{{url('build/js/custom.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: `progressbar()` is from which JS plugin?

Comment: is `progressbar` JS included in markup? If so, check path of `progressbar` js is correct?

Comment: AFAIK this is a jQueryUI function, which you haven't included

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below code

```
NProgress.start();
NProgress.done();
```

Reference document https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress

I guess you are using `nprogress`.

Answer (score 0):

try to order how jquery javascript etc are loaded... change order and moving it from bottom to head...

Answer (score -1):

```
// Progressbar
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(".progress .progress-bar")[0]) {
    $('.progress .progress-bar').progressbar();
}
})
```

Comment: Its not Working @Rajesh Meena

Comment: Same Error Display Boss @Rajesh Meena

Comment: please check progressbar Js path

Comment: this is the code that throws the error, how is it an answer?